# Why cant I simply check if a variable is null instead of checking for different exceptions?

Tags: java

Consider this, if `userChoice` is not an integer:

```
Scanner choice = new Scanner(System.in);
int userChoice = choice.nextInt();
if(....){
    .... //not important
}
else if(userChoice == null){
    System.out.println("wrong input..");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Why cant I do this? And instead have to do:

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

..... //bunch of code

Scanner choice = new Scanner(System.in);
    int userChoice;
    try {
        userChoise = choice.nextInt();
        if(...){
          ..... //not important
        }
    }
    catch(InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("wrong input..");
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

I thought it was so that if I inputed, say, a `char` when it expected an `int` it would simply return `null`. So if I checked for null then it would be sufficient. So what am I missing/not understading?

So this is not a question regarding the Scanner library. If you want to boil it down it was that I did not know that a integer could not be `null`. So the user who thought that this was duplicated, it might be. But it is certainly not a duplicate to the post that you suggested..

Comment: `int` can never be `null`. Never!

Comment: Scanner Class throws Exception on input mismatch instead `null` which an `int` can not be

Comment: This may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/970029/423955 Java primitive types cannot be null. Only references to Objects can be null.

Comment: there is a `hasNextInt()` method for a purpose ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validating input using java.util.Scanner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059333/validating-input-using-java-util-scanner)

Answer (score 4):

An `int` cannot be null. It can be any number in its range.

Comment: Please be more precise: an `int` cannot be null; an `Integer` can; `integer` is not a thing in Java.

Comment: I did say integer not `Integer` and int is short for: integer.

Comment: @AndyTurner I thought an `int` was short for `integer`?

Comment: @Shiro So ther is a diffrence bewteen `integer` and `Integer` ?!??!!

Comment: @FelixRosén obviously it is; but by saying "integer", it is not clear whether you are referring to `Integer` (which can be null) or `int` (which cannot be null).

Comment: Are you happy now?

Comment: @AndyTurner So ther is a diffrence bewteen `integer` and `Integer` ??

Comment: @FelixRosén Have a look at this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html

Comment: @FelixRosén yes. `Integer` usually refers to `java.lang.Integer`; `integer` is not a standard type in Java.

Comment: @Shiro yes. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that you need to use Integer instead of int if you want to return null, it is not advisable. The main reason is that checking an output for null is easily forgotten and may lead to error situations much later in the program.

An exception, though, has to be catched or it climbs up the stack. Exceptions make it much easier to find out where an error happens (if they have proper content, they also say why it happened).